# Show text only if sidebar fully expands

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar that expands when it is moused over.  Once it expands I would like for text to appear.  When I am no longer moused over the sidebar, I would like the text to disappear.  This is simple enough with the exception of one circumstance that I'm having trouble with.

**The Problem:**  As I currently have it configured, if I casually mouse over the sidebar but then exit before the sidebar expands, the text appears in the collapsed sidebar.  This is a minor annoyance but I was wondering if there is a way to only make the text appear once the bar has fully expanded.  I suppose I might be able to use an `.on()` event to watch for the sidebar to expand to its full size, but this seems needlessly heavy (maybe I'm wrong).

Anyway, here's my code.  Any tips would be very appreciated.

```js
$('div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus').hide();
$("div#sidebar-wrapper").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: 0
  });
  $('div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus').delay(800).fadeIn(500);
});

$('div#sidebar-wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
  $('div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus').fadeOut(500);
  $(this).animate({
    left: -127
  });
});
```

```css
span#nus {
  color: #38353D;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  // background-image: url("/assets/homebg.png");
  background: #2DBE60;
  // margin-left: -150px;

  /*     left: 70px; */
  width: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden
}
#sidebar_menu li a,
.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #ddd;
  // display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 170px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1A1A1A;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s;
  -moz-transition: background .5s;
  -o-transition: background .5s;
  -ms-transition: background .5s;
  transition: background .5s;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace {
  height: 60px;
}
div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace img {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 35px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus {
  // visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 40pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 46px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper a.link {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="dashboard" style="left: -127px;">
  <div id="logospace">
    <img src="/assets/initial.svg">
    <span id="nus" style="display: none;">Appear</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working fine. isn't?

Comment: @GopsAB Thanks for the response.  For the most part yes.  The problem is when I mouse over the sidebar but then pull the mouse away before the bar fully expands, the text still appears (but it's all crammed in the little sidebar).  I want to prevent the text from displaying unless the sidebar expands to its full size.

Answer (score 0):

You can show comment after animation complete

```js
$('div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus').hide();
$("div#sidebar-wrapper").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: 0
  }, function(){
    $('div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus').clearQueue()
.stop().delay(800).fadeIn(500);
  });
  
}, function(){
 $('div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus').clearQueue()
.stop().fadeOut(500);
  
  $(this).animate({
    left: -127
  });
   });
```

```css
span#nus {
  color: #38353D;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  // background-image: url("/assets/homebg.png");
  background: #2DBE60;
  // margin-left: -150px;

  /*     left: 70px; */
  width: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden
}
#sidebar_menu li a,
.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #ddd;
  // display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 170px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1A1A1A;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s;
  -moz-transition: background .5s;
  -o-transition: background .5s;
  -ms-transition: background .5s;
  transition: background .5s;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace {
  height: 60px;
}
div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace img {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 35px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus {
  // visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 40pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 46px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper a.link {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="dashboard" style="left: -127px;">
  <div id="logospace">
    <img src="/assets/initial.svg">
    <span id="nus" style="display: none;">Appear</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  However in your fiddle, I'm still running into the same problem: If I remove the mouse from the sidebar before it fully expands, the text still appears.

Comment: Looks like need to stop previous animation

Comment: `.stop()` will almost solve the problem. But what he really needs is a `complete` callback that won't fire unless animation is 100% completed. I don't understand why jquery's `complete` or even `done` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`.animate()` has several callback functions available. Meaning that you can execute code after animation is complete, or during, or even before if you want to. Checkout the jquery documentation for [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#callbacks) for more information.

I would write your code like this:

```
$('div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus').hide();
$("div#sidebar-wrapper").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    left: 0
  }, function() {
    $('div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus').fadeIn();
  });

});

$('div#sidebar-wrapper').mouseleave(function() {

  $(this).stop().animate({
    left: -127
  }, function() {
    $('div#sidebar-wrapper div#logospace span#nus').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5wbbLc5/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the problem seems to persist.  https://jsfiddle.net/neanderslob/4chzw80n/8/

Comment: Thanks for the update in the fiddle.  Unfortunately it still seems to have the original problem:  If I stop hovering before it has a chance to fully expand, the text still appears in the collapsed box.

Comment: I see your problem now, .stop() won't solve it completely but it's halfway there. I'm looking for a better solution. I updated my answer with a little bit, see if this is close enough

Comment: Thanks for the update, and for trying to help me figure it out.